# Spring MVC equivalent for Struts 2 Preparable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts2

Is there something similar to Struts 2 Preparable interface / prepare method in Spring 3 MVC?

That is, a method executed every time the controller is requested.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: What I want to achieve, for example, is to fill a group of properties depending on the user I am, for every request in this controller, trying to avoid this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("my")
public class MyController {

    private void fillProperties() {...}

    public void request1() {
        fillProperties();
        ...
    }

    public void request2() {
        fillProperties();
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no direct equivalent to do this, because Spring MVC controllers are generally shared singletons, so this technique would be a bad idea. Rather than looking for a direct equivalent, how about telling us what you'rte trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited my question. As you can see, my idea is a bit generic. I don't understand the problem of this technique. I've succesly used Struts2+Spring, that is, Spring instantiating Struts2 actions as beans. In that case actions were shared singletons too, didn't them?

Comment: Instead of psuedo code please elaborate a bit more on what you want. Is this different per controller? Is it for all controllers? Are those properties at the controller level or from the model handled by the controller. There is currently too little information and code to give a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options:

- use a [ServletFilter](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html)
- add an [AOP before advise point cut](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-before) to match the controller method(s) you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a constructor `MyController(){}`
- and call all methods

or

- You can also use annotations 
  **@postconstruct** and **@predestroy** annotations

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html